# Efficient way of updating real time location using django-channels/websocket

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-channels

I am working on Real Time based app, it needs to update location of user whenever it is changed.

***Android app*** is used as frontend, which get location using ***Google/Fused Api*** and in `onLocationChanged(loc:Location)`, I am sending the latest location over the ***Websocket***. The location update is then received by a ***django channel consumer***, and job of this consumer is to store location in database asynchronously (I am using `@database_sync_to_async` decorator.

But the problem is, server crashes when Android app tries to send 10-15 location updates per second. What will be the efficient way of updating real time location?

Note: Code can be supplied on demand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask yourself what kind of resolution you need for that data. Do you really need 10 updates a second? If not, take every nth update or see if Android will just give you the updates slower. Secondly, look for a native async database library. @database_sync_to_async runs a different thread every time you call it which kills the performance gains you're getting from the event loop. If you say in one thread you'll keep the CPU caches fresh. You won't get to use the ORM. But do you really need a database or would Redis work? If so, call aioredis directly and it will be a lot faster since its in memory and you can use it's fast data structures like queues and sets. If you need Redis to be even faster look at it's multithreaded fork KeyDB.